# How can I set my keyboard layout up similar to macOS?

Tags: keyboard

The basic stuff: I want to be able to switch apps with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, copy and paste with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> for most contexts with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl']"
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a GUI to make the same change:

- install dconf-tools from the software center
- run the dconf-editor application
- navigate to org > gnome > desktop > input sources
- change the value of kbd-options to ['ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl']

That should take care of most shortcuts. The shortcut to switch windows can be changed from <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to something else on the standard keyboard shortcuts page in System Settings.

Comment: I can't seem to confirm that this works; I ran the command (and double-checked it in dconf-editor) and all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> shortcuts are as they were.

Comment: Cassidy, try logging out/rebooting.

Comment: One issue is sometimes you really want `Ctrl` to be `Ctrl`, like while in a terminal and not the apple key.

Comment: @Ray I concur, the ideal solution would be for Elementary OS to start using `Super` like Mac uses `Cmd` and then when you really need `Ctrl` it is still available on the keyboard.

Comment: Confirmed that this works for most things now; however, it gets confusing very quickly because the keyboard shortcuts in the OS still refer to the original mappings.

Answer (score 0):

How about remapping the keys? [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) should do the trick there.

Assuming that your command button is replaced with meta (I can't help you there, I don't own a Mac) this should work for you:

`xmodmap -e "remove control = Control_L"
xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"
xmodmap -e "add control = Super_L"
xmodmap -e "add mod4 = Control_L"`

This will work until you end your session.

**Permanent solution**

1) Make `~/.Xmodmap` file.

2) Write  this into it:

`remove control = Control_L
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L
add mod4 = Control_L`

3) You should now somehow put `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to run at startup (I'm having trouble to find out how right now, will fix later).

Comment: I've tried all possible solutions i found online (putting in Switchboard > startup, putting it in ~/.xinitrc file,  /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc file, ...) but nothing happens. This could be a bug.

You could put it in your .bashrc file but it will be ran only when you start the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this GitHub issue in the official Elementary OS repo https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/69. It's a long story but it helps...

Comment: Hi @luiarhs! Thanks for sharing this resource answer. To make this into a complete answer, could you add a brief summary of that link's contents? Answers that consist of only a link are not considered complete in Stack Exchange sites.